# How can i make like this design in Android app

Tags: android

how can i do this design in android [first step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ff7uQ.png) [button indictor continue with second steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFFoj.png)

Comment: You can do this easily with Compose.

Comment: Hey Welcome ! Please post your tried solutions so that community can guide you instead of writing code for you.

Comment: Can you tell me how , or give me link of it

Comment: You can [edit] it, there is a button on bottom of your question. Also, please make a [mre]